# Thymeleaf not displaying images from base64 strings in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, email, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application where I'm using Thymeleaf to display images received as base64 strings in the frontend. However, despite passing the base64 strings to Thymeleaf, the images are not being displayed.And this thymeleaf template is send by mail

Here's a simplified version of my code:

1.I have a 'TaskDto' class with a field 'assignedToLogo' of type 'byte[]' and a corresponding field 'assignedToLogoString' as a 'base64' representation.

```
@Data

    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)

    public class TaskDto extends BaseDto {

    private byte[] assignedToLogo;
    private String assignedToLogoString;
    private String assignedToName;
    }
```

2.I'm using Thymeleaf to iterate over a list of tasks (todayitems) and trying to display the associated images:

```
<!-- Thymeleaf template in HTML -->
    <div th:each="item : ${todayitems}">
    <span>
    <img th:src="${item.assignedToLogoString}" style="height: 25px;">
    <span style="margin-left: 4px;">
    <span th:text="${item.assignedToName}"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
    </div>
```

3.The 'convert' method is converting the 'assignedToLogo' from 'byte[]' to a 'base64' string:

```
@Service

public class EmailGeneratorService {

@Value("${send.notification.mail.template.name1}")
private String SEND_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE_NAME;

@Autowired
private ProjectClient projectClient;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

public void sendMailTemplate(UserDto userDto) {
    Mail emailRequest = new Mail();
    String[] email = new String[] { userDto.getEmail() };
    emailRequest.setTo(email);
    emailRequest.setSubject("Test Email");
    emailRequest.setContent("This is the content of the email. You can use HTML if needed.");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    
    ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> res = projectClient.getTodaysTaskFromAllProjectsForMail(Utils.getLongValueFromEncryptedString(userDto.getId()),
            userDto.getRole().name());
    List<TaskDto> allTasksOfToday = mapper.convertValue(res.getBody().getData(), new TypeReference<List<TaskDto>>() {});
    List<TaskDto> todaysTask = convert(allTasksOfToday);

    try {
        javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,
                MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        // Thymeleaf template processing
        Context context = initializeThymeleafContext(emailRequest,todaysTask);

        String emailTemplate = templateEngine.process(SEND_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE_NAME, context);
        mimeMessageHelper.setText(emailTemplate, true);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to send email: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

private Context initializeThymeleafContext(Mail emailRequest,List<TaskDto> todaysTask) {
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("emailContent", emailRequest.getContent());
    context.setVariable("todayitems", todaysTask);
    return context;
}

private static List<TaskDto> convert(List<TaskDto> taskDtos) {
    
    for (TaskDto task : taskDtos) {

        //task.getAssignedToLogo is in byte form.
        String base64Logo = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(task.getAssignedToLogo());
        System.out.println(base64Logo);
        task.setAssignedToLogoString(base64Logo);
    }
    return taskDtos;
}
```

Issue:

Despite implementing the conversion of assignedToLogo to a base64 string and passing it to Thymeleaf, the images are not being displayed on the frontend.

Additional Context:

I've verified that the base64 strings are correctly generated.
There are no errors in the browser console.
I'm using Thymeleaf with Spring Boot for template rendering.

Question:

Can someone please help me identify the issue in my code or provide suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this problem? Am I missing something in the Thymeleaf template or in my Java code?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you view the source in a browser window, what shows up?

Comment: <img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_Nbrb8-szHFrGW_eS6JOKObXHA6yBXyxX4LqQGdE0iXFdvU76X4E_EtkRqSRQW93KFvee3PKXqghr6GVFejuZb-4att63yOwICuetMKrecgSC5h09N7yNspg3FiWq_NSEu9VnEfX2pFIFuM5MPueg-KZQL3UNsRTproYyvABebZulVWvRpl72otP-1EkLY7IfsqvRFMeARbZ1LHHS5js7k4mtfxVSGNM59Ln-Lp5iJVr6sVK9EMk-fqO_bCM3I-xCdKFq3G1ggzylf6_e1QgQjkKBbX7zAC5f92W5YRVyJsQeUaGC19Gt9K2ED4DKmUBKaqW8QdpraMJ0JZNla1_ffSm6wtBGEDYgVd0akyKHhgXMEelx87FJK6zc7QOdQ_0.........." style="height:25px" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" jslog="138226; u014N:xr6bB; 53:WzAsMl0.">

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your **assignedLogoToString** has **"data:image/jpg;base64,"** prefix. If not, add it to your Java code,

```
task.setAssignedToLogoString("data:image/jpg;base64,"+base64Logo);
```

Or you can add it to your thymeleaf template:

```
<img th:src="data:image/jpg;base64,${item.assignedToLogoString}" style="height: 25px;">
```

I prefer to add it to the thymeleaf template.

Comment: i tried it already but it is not showing image